# create self-extracting archive (sfx exe) in-memory with python

Tags: python, zip, 7zip, sfx

I need to create a self-extracting archive exe file in-memory and upload it to GCS.
I know 7zip can do that but as far as I see, py7zr doesn't support SFX files.

Does someone know how to do that?